# How to count data with specify word?

Tags: sql

I am a new face to SQL.
Suppose I have a set of data:

```
==================
|| iphone6      ||
|| iphone7      ||
|| iphone7s     ||
|| Android 7.1  ||
|| Android 6.3  ||
==================
```

And I want to get the result like this:

```
||Model      ||Amount   ||
==========================
||iphone     ||        3||
||Android    ||        2||
==========================
```

And my code is like this:

```
SELECT
CASE
   WHEN model LIKE '%Android%' THEN 'Android'
   WHEN model LIKE '%iPhone%' THEN 'IPhone'
END,
, COUNT(*) AS Amount FROM #table GROUP BY model;
```

But my output is :

```
||Model     ||    Amount||
==========================
||IPhone    ||         1||
||IPhone    ||         1||
||IPhone    ||         1||
||Android   ||         1||
||Android   ||         1||
==========================
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: You are almost there. Make this change in your query: `...CASE
   WHEN model LIKE '%Android%' THEN 'Android'
   WHEN model LIKE '%iPhone%' THEN 'IPhone'
END AS brand.......GROUP BY brand`

Comment: Your code is not MySQL.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: If it is not SQL, then what is it?

Comment: Since i am using Joomla to develop website

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to aggregate by the column you are creating:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN model LIKE '%Android%' THEN 'Android'
             WHEN model LIKE '%iPhone%' THEN 'IPhone'
        END),
       COUNT(*) AS Amount
FROM #table
GROUP BY (CASE WHEN model LIKE '%Android%' THEN 'Android'
               WHEN model LIKE '%iPhone%' THEN 'IPhone'
          END);
```

Comment: @IvanCheung Note that for this specific example, the first '%' is unnecessary. On an appropriately indexed table, this query will run faster without it.

Comment: @Strawberry . . . Actually, an index would probably not be used for a `case` statement.  You seem to be confusing this logic with the logic of a `where` clause.